# Show the ListView and my bar together doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, tabs

I'm right now coding an simple feature into my app. Just have a look on my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmN6G.png) - I don't know why my tab is everytime behind the listview. Could you please help me?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards

listview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you add your styles.xml file ??

Comment: I've added the styles.xml. Hope that will help you...

Comment: Which theme have you set in the manifest file for this activity ?

Comment: AppTheme.NoActionBar - I think this is the mistake?

Comment: It's not a mistake if you use that and still you want actionbar then you will need to add a toolbar in your layout file and set it as your action bar in activity

Comment: And at which place do I have to insert this? What makes me confused is, that in my listview.xml is no bar, but if I render the design there is the bar?

Comment: In design preview you can change the theme and see there is a drop down from which you can select the theme

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"> <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> </style>
```

This is causing the the ActionBar go disappear, if you want to use that theme than you will need to add a `Toolbar` to your layout file and set it as `ActionBar` in your `Activity`

For e.g

```
setSupportActionBar(yourtoolbar); // add to activity XML file and refer to it using findViewById() as you do with other views
```